# Cloudinary TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I'm getting this error when trying to configure cloudify:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

cloudify.js

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const cloudinaryStorage = require("multer-storage-cloudinary");
const multer = require("multer");

cloudinary.config({        //ERROR
  cloud_name: 'somthing',
  api_key: '12345678',
  api_secret: 'a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1'
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myhoop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "cloudinary.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "^1.19.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.4",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-storage-cloudinary": "^2.2.1",
    "prompt": "^1.0.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

I am following the documentation [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#getting_started_guide). Am I missing somthing obvious?

Comment: have you done ```npm install cloudinary ```

Comment: navigate to `cloudinary` in node_modules and look for an export file. There should be a config being exported. Tell me if you could find it

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz I'm not seeing an export file

Comment: @AyushKatiyar I have.